# Devise gem. First user working incorretly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So I have several users in my app. I have a controller method that allows users to view liked posts of other users. Everything works correctly until I try to view first user's liked posts. I get an error: undefined method `comment_path'. I also can only login with my username but not with my email. All this errors are only related to the first user in my app. What could be wrong?
**Posts_controller.rb:**

```
def liked
 @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
 @posts = @user.find_liked_items
 render action: :index
end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<div id="posts"> 
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <div class="box">
        <p style="color: #bbb">by <%= link_to post.user.username, liked_posts_path(username: post.user.username) %></p>
        <p id="text"><%= link_to post do %><%= truncate(post.content, length:400){ link_to ' read full', post, {:style=>'color:#bbb'} } %><% end %></p>
        ...
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**Routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
 collection do
   get :recent
   get :hot
   get :liked
 end
 member do
   put 'like', to: "posts#like"
   put 'unlike', to: "posts#unlike"
 end
 resources :comments do
   collection do
     get :fresh
     get :hot
   end
   member do
     put 'like', to: "comments#like"
     put 'unlike', to: "comments#unlike"
   end
 end
end

root to: "posts#hot"
```

Comment: Post code that relate to issue, start from controller method.

Comment: @AlbertPaul, I added the code

Comment: Undefined method `comment_path` means that you have not created the route correctly. Add your `config/routes.rb`

Answer (score 0):

In view file, try changing this,

```
<%= link_to post.user.username, liked_posts_path(post.user.id) %>
```

In liked method change code,

```
@user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
```

See if this works, it's always a better practice to pass ID instead of other attributes, because of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I dropped my database and now its working

Answer (score 0):

In devise the default authentication mechanism is email. According to devise documentation you can specify your custom authentication in application_controller.rb like:

```
  def configure_permitted_parameters
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:login, :username, :email, :password, :remember_me) }
   devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end
```

Also see: [How To: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

So the other problem does not seems like devise error could you specify it with more details pls.